# Visualforce: How to make outputlabel display above an inputfield?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have this as my visualforce page code:

```
<apex:pageblockSection id="thepbs" columns="4">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.Name.Label}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!acc.Name}" id="accName" required="false"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Country"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!acc.BillingCountry}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Contact Name"/>
                <apex:inputText value="{!contactName}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.Type.Label}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!acc.Type}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        </apex:pageblockSection>
```

In my UI, it looks like this:
[image]

I want to make the labels above the inputfields.. Can anyone please help me? Thank you very much.

I want to make it look like this:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this you need to use table to create the UI you want

```
 Option 1 : 

    <apex:page  docType="html-5.0" >
     <apex:form>
        <table>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
            <th>Three</th>
            <th>Four</th>
            <tr>
                <td><apex:inputText></apex:inputText></td>
                <td><apex:inputText></apex:inputText></td>
                <td><apex:inputText></apex:inputText></td>
                <td><apex:inputText></apex:inputText></td>
            </tr>
         </table>   

     </apex:form>
    </apex:page>

    Option 2: Alignment wont look good 

    <apex:page  docType="html-5.0" >
        <apex:Pageblock>
            <apex:form>
                <apex:pageblocksection id="thepbs" columns="4">
                    <apex:pageblocksectionItem>
                        <apex:outputLabel style="align:left">Field One</apex:outputLabel>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionItem> 
                    <apex:pageblocksectionItem>
                        <apex:outputLabel style="align:left">Field Two</apex:outputLabel>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionItem> 
                    <apex:pageblocksectionItem>
                        <apex:outputLabel style="align:left">Field Three</apex:outputLabel>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionItem> 
                    <apex:pageblocksectionItem>
                        <apex:outputLabel style="align:left">Field Four</apex:outputLabel>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionItem> 
                </apex:pageblocksection>
                <apex:pageblocksection id="thepbs1" columns="4">
                    <apex:pageblocksectionItem>
                        <apex:inputText/>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionItem> 
                    <apex:pageblocksectionItem>
                        <apex:inputText/>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionItem>  
                    <apex:pageblocksectionItem>
                        <apex:inputText/>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionItem>  
                    <apex:pageblocksectionItem>
                        <apex:inputText/>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionItem>  
                </apex:pageblocksection>
            </apex:form>
        </apex:Pageblock>

    </apex:page>
```

Pageblock section render as table so you can use html table tags to create the desired UI.